# opencart error Class 'Log'

Tags: php, error-handling

I kindly need assistance. My site was working fine until I installed this module:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5985

I did everything as instructed by the developer but now my entire site is screwed up. When I try to load the backend I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Log' not found in /home/mhxhh/public_html/admin/index.php on line 58
```

and when I try to load the frontend I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Log' not found in /home/mhxhh/public_html/index.php on line 75
```

I have now removed all the files from these module plus the google and bing verification files but no change the errors are still being reproduced. Please assist as I dont know what to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, except not associated with the extension you mentioned (I don't believe).  I found this link, which explained the fix for me: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=108291.

Issue was that my /system/library/log.php file had become 0 bytes somehow.  It needed to be re-uploaded, or in my case, I just cut and pasted the content from another OC site I am running.  Saved and refreshed browser, and the site was up and running again!

This was the content of my log.php file:

```
<?php
final class Log {
private $filename;

public function __construct($filename) {
    $this->filename = $filename;
}

public function write($message) {
    $file = DIR_LOGS . $this->filename;

    $handle = fopen($file, 'a+'); 

    fwrite($handle, date('Y-m-d G:i:s') . ' - ' . $message . "\n");

    fclose($handle); 
}
}
?>
```

Hope this helps - Cheers.